# How can the angle between any two azimuth dip pairs be found?

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d

The order of rotation is azimuth then dip. I've tried pythagoras style answers but testing showed it was the wrong approach. How can I find the angle between any two pairs?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you turn your [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) into [cartesian ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) of unit length. Then the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) between the vectors can be computed easily, and it is equal to the cosine of the angle.